# fsockopen not working?

Tags: php, sockets, fsockopen

I am trying to connect to an IRC server via PHP on a command line using Windows 7.

Everytime when running this:

```
$socket = fsockopen($irc_server, 6667, $errno, $errstr, 5);
```

`$errno` = 0, `$errstr` = "" and `$socket` = 'Resource id #4' (using `die($socket);`)

What is the cause of this, and how can I debug more into this.

The following code:

```
$s = fsockopen("google.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 5);
die($errno.", ".$errstr.", ".$s);
```

...returns the following:

```
0, , Resource id #4
```

I can't use `$socket`. It says "Invalid resource" when I try to use it. Also, the PHP documentation notes that errno 0 indicates a wrongly opened socket.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Aaand the problem is exactly...? Resource ID is just the ID of the socket. Go ahead and use it.

Comment: I can't use it. It says "Invalid resource" when I try to use it. Also, the PHP documentation notes that errno 0 indicates a wrongly opened socket.

Comment: A sorry, didn't see the 'invalid ' part. Well, go see what errno 0 means. What does "$irc_server" contain?

Comment: You probably didn't see the errno 0 part either.

Comment: Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in C:\ircBot\irc.php on line 7

Which is:

fwrite($socket,$cmd,strlen($cmd));

Comment: Maybe in that code you used "$s = fsockopen..." and thus you should use $s and not $socket? That happens to me quite often, too.

Comment: LukeN: $socket is in his code (first part of question), the second part is from php.net therefore $s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you show us a little more of your code?

What happens with this code:

```
$s = fsockopen($irc_server, 6667, $errno, $errstr, 5);
if ($s === false) {
  die($errno.", ".$errstr.", ".$s);
} else {
  // your code with socket
  die("Valid socket resource");
}
```

?

Comment: irCmd does not know the $socket variable. It is the problem I think.

Comment: Read my answer to this question, I fixed it.

Comment: I suggested it first :-) and now off I go.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.

function irCmd didn't know $socket, so I put this in front of it:

```
global $socket;
```

And it worked. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: And that's why globals are BAD.

Comment: Why don't you simply make it a parameter of irCmd? It is a solution for now but consider what happens if you want to be connected to more servers.. You'll have to rewrite it therefore it's better to write it properly in the first place.

Comment: I don't get why, but that actually solved my problem. What is irCmd btw ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says (emphasis mine):

> If the value returned in `errno` is 0 **and the function returned `FALSE`**, it is an indication that the error occurred before the `connect()` call. This is most likely due to a problem initializing the socket.

Since the function did not return false, the socket is valid. If you are having further problems, tells us what they are; `fsockopen` has returned normally here.

Comment: fwrite($socket,$cmd,strlen($cmd)); tells me I've passed an "Invalid resource".